# Attend event form with ajax

Tags: custom-post-types, functions, ajax, forms

I've created a Wordpress website with gigs from a band. All the logged in users can select if they've attended that specific gig. Something like setlist.fm.

So I've created a new table `wp_gigs_attending`. This table has 3 fields:

1. attending_id
2. post_id
3. user_id

The attending_id is ofcourse the primary key (A.I), the post_id is the id of the gig you've attended and the user_id is your user id, so the id of the current user.

Everything works, but I've added my PHP code in my template and also without ajax. When I click on the form, the page refreshes, which doesn't looks very good.

So I want to submit that form (only a button) with ajax.

On the **single-gig.php** template:

```
<?php if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {  ?>
    <div class="attended">
        <form method="post" id="attending" class="attended__form">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="attend" />
        </form>
    </div>
<?php } ?>

<script>
    jQuery(function(){
        jQuery('#attending').on('submit', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();

            jQuery.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                url: '<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/inc/attend.php',
                data: jQuery('#attending').serialize(),
                succes: function(){
                    alert('form was succesfully submitted');
                }
            })
        });
    });
</script>
```

In my /inc folder I have to code that check if I've already attended that gig or not.

1. If I haven't attended that gig -> click on form button -> insert row in table
2. If I have attended that gig -> click on form button -> delete that row.

This is the code in **attended-gig.php**:

```
//get the user id
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
$current_user_id = $current_user->ID;

//get the post id
$current_post_id = get_the_ID();

//check if already attended
$attending = $wpdb->get_var(
    $wpdb->prepare(
        "SELECT attending_id FROM " . $wpdb->prefix . "gigs_attending
        WHERE user_id = %d AND post_id = %d LIMIT 1",
        $current_user_id, $current_post_id
    )
);

if ( $attending > 0 ) {
    $isAttending = true;
} else {
    $isAttending = false;
}


//actions
if($isAttending == false) {
    //if not attended yet, insert the user_id and post_id in the table
    $success = $wpdb->insert("wp_gigs_attending", array(
        "user_id" => $current_user_id,
        "post_id" => $current_post_id,
    ));

} else {
    //if attended yet, delete the row in the table
    $succes = $wpdb->get_var(
        $wpdb->prepare(
            "DELETE FROM " . $wpdb->prefix . "gigs_attending
            WHERE user_id = %d AND post_id = %d LIMIT 1",
            $current_user_id, $current_post_id
        )
    );
}
```

I know that the queries are working fine. But I receive a 500 (internal server error) on that file.

The wanted result:

1. A user hasn't attended that specific gig yet -> Clicks on the button -> inserts a new row in the table -> the button has now an extra class, so that it is visible that he attended that gig.
2. A user maybe made a mistake and selected that he attended a specific gig. He clicks on the same button to undo it -> delete that row in the table -> removes the extra class on the button.

When a user goes to the singe-gig.php, it must be visible that he already attended that gig, so the `attended` class must by there on that button.

Comment: And you can't find an error in your logs? What happens in ```/inc/attend.php```?

Comment: I'd highly recommend using AJAX in combination with https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/admin_url/. You can create a script that handles your AJAX request on i.e. www.example.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=attendEvent. You can include this script within the functions.php file (https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_ajax_(action)). Please note that you might want to add the nopriv rule in order to make it work without being logged in.

Answer (score 0):

First of all. You'll need to follow the [ajax best practices in Wordpress](https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/using-ajax-with-wordpress/). That means, add the right actions for your functions and call them also with the admin ajax url.

So your jQuery ajax should call the admin_url, and you'll need to send along an 'action' data in this example, the name of the action: 'subscribe'; (wp_ajax_subscribe minus the wp_ajax_ ). *You can include that with a hidden input field called with name 'action' and value 'subscribe', so you serialize function picks it up from the submit event.*

```
url: '<?php echo admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )?>',

add_action( 'wp_ajax_subscribe', 'ja_ajax_subscribe' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_subscribe', 'ja_ajax_subscribe' );

function ja_ajax_subscribe(){

   $result = 'some data';

   wp_send_json_success($result);
}
```